# How to find the relationship between an independent variable in a time series and a single dependent variable

Tags: machine-learning, correlation

I have a dataset of crop yield of a seasonal crop, under environmental conditions (rainfall, humidity, temperature etc.). Daily environmental conditions are recorded over few years with the crop yield of each season.

example:

Date , Temperature , Humidity , Rainfall

1/31/2019 , 28 , 64.55 , 1.2

2/1/2019 , 28.2 , 65.81 , 1.2

2/2/2019 , 28 ,  67.18 , 0.6

2/3/2019 , 28 ,  68.54 , 0.4

2/4/2019 , 27.43 ,  69.17 , 0.2

Crop yield for the above season is 37000kg.

Can you guide me on how can I find the relationships between the crop yield (dependent) and each environment factor (independent)? I am trying to find the impact of each factor on the crop yield of a season but I am having a hard time figuring out how to find correlation between a time series (environment factor) and a single variable (crop yield).